# applying multi animations in one component using Framer motion variants

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, animation, framer-motion

I am new by Framer motion, what I am trying to do  is imitating wheel motion by   moving image while it is rotating
I don't know  how to make this work
I have tried something like this but it doesn't work

```
    const imageRuning :Variants = {
                                   hidden:{
                                          x:"-100vw",
                                          opacity:0
                                         },
                                  visible:{
                                          x:0,
                                          opacity:1,
                                          transitionDuration:"3s"

                                           },
                                   rotation:{
                                            rotate:[180,0],
                                            transition:{
                                                  repeat:Infinity,
                                                  type:"tween",
                                                  ease:"linear"
                                                  }
                                             }
                                       }
  
            const  HomePage =()=> {

                   return (

                        <div className={style.animationContainer}>
                             <motion.img 
                                  className={style.animatedImage}
                                  variants={imageRuning}
                                  initial="hidden"
                                  animate={["visible","rotation"]}
                                  width={100} height={100} src="/static/me.jpg" >
                             </motion.img>
                        </div>
              )
```

any help please ,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to animate two properties (`x` and `rotate`) with different transition values.

You can only animate to one variant at a time, so if you want them to happen at the same time, you'll need to combine those into a single variant. Luckily, you can specify unique transition values for any animating property by listing it within the `transition` object.

Like this:

```
visible: {
  x: 0,
  opacity: 1,
  rotate: 180, // rotate and x animate in the same variant
  transition: {
    duration: 3, // default transition duration (applies to x and opacity)
    rotate: {
      // unique transition for rotate property only
      repeat: Infinity,
      type: "tween",
      ease: "linear"
    }
  }
}
```

The way you have it set up, the object will continue rotating even after the x animation finishes (`repeat: Infinity`). Is that what you want? You can look into [Animation Controls](https://www.framer.com/docs/animation/#component-animation-controls) if you want more control.

Comment: There is no `rotate` prop on `transition`

Comment: @TanNguyen You can use any animatable property inside `transition` to define a unique transition for that specific property.